# Finding unused views/partials in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently working on a largish Ruby on Rails project. It's old enough and big enough that it's not clear if all views are actually in use.

Is there any script/plugin out there that can generate a list of unused view files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wrote a script to find unused partials/views. I assumed, though, that "unused" means that a view-file is present for which no controller-method is defined (any more). The script does not check whether the view is called because there is no link from the default-route to it. This would have been far more complex.

Place the following script in the application's script folder:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'config/environment'
(Dir['app/controllers/*.rb'] - ['app/controllers/application.rb']).each do |c|
  require c
  base = File.basename(c, '.rb')
  views = Hash.new
  Dir["app/views/#{base.split('_')[0]}/*"].each do |v|
    views.store(File.basename(v).split('.')[0], v)
  end
  unused_views = views.keys - Object.const_get(base.camelcase).public_instance_methods - ApplicationController.public_instance_methods
  puts "Unused views for #{base.camelcase}:" if unused_views.size > 0
  unused_views.each { |v| puts views[v] }
end
```

It is kinda hackish and unfinished, but it does the job - at least for me.

Execute it like this (you only need to change the execute-bit the first time with chmod):

```
chmod +x script/script_name
./script/script_name
```

Enjoy!

Comment: You should require config/environment. At least I had to, because we use gettext. Then you can also remove the next line (requiring rubygems, etc.)

Comment: It also doesn't handle partials and stuff like `render :action => "view"`. But it's a good start.

Comment: With a Rails 5.2 with Ruby 2.7, there are load error on file that exists and just have a single empty method.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at the following script on GitHub http://github.com/vinibaggio/discover-unused-partials

Comment: I downvoted this since the gem seems to have a compatibility issue with recent Ruby.

Answer (score 5):

Just install and run the **[discover-unused-partials](https://github.com/vinibaggio/discover-unused-partials)** gem:

```bash
gem install discover-unused-partials

discover-unused-partials rails_root_directory
```

Comment: Downvoted this answer too since the gem seems to have a compatibility issue with recent Ruby.

Answer (score 3):

Iterate through your partials, grep (or awk) the project for the name of the file. Adjust your search regex to look for "render :partial" at beginning of line for generic partials (eg, "_form").

Comment: `:partial` is optionnal now so this doesn't apply at all now